# Copy constructor and const

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

Here is the code i'm having problem with

```
class MyString {
    char* str;
public:
    MyString(const char* _str) : str(_str) {}
}
```

This is the error message from the compiler

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]

Is this because `str` is `char*` and `_str` is `const char*`?

Should the copy( I mean `str(_str)` ) be the exact same type (REGARDING `const`)?

How could I modify this code into reasonable code? I want to keep `MyString(const char* _str)` as `const char*`.

Comment: That's not a _copy constructor_! And the types need to be the exact same, yes.

Comment: How could I modify this code into a reasonable code?

Comment: Don't assign that pointer to your internally kept class member. You need to allocate and manage memory for it to hold a copy of what the pointer parameter points to. I guess that's the purpose of this constructor function.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes.

Longs answer:
`const char* str` is a pointer to a region in memory that contains a c string. By marking it `const` you are saying that it may not be changed. You are attempting to create a new pointer to the same memory region, but this new pointer says that region may be changed, which the compiler complains about (since the original says that this is not allowed).

Note that you are currently not copying the contents to the string (which I suspect you want), but the pointer to the string. To actually copy the string you must first allocate memory and then copy the contents. Or just use a `std::string` instead, which manages all this for you.

Comment: int size = 3;
const int _size = size;
works but not const char* and char*...
Is this related to pointer?

Comment: @mbae059 It's related to c style strings (zero terminated sequence of characters), which aren't intrinsic types unfortunately. Standard c++ covers this gap with the `std::string` class.

Comment: @mbae059 That works because it copies a value; you instantiate a copy of the original integer. With pointers you are not copying the value it is pointing at, so the new pointer needs to be `const` as well.

Comment: This answer is essentially correct, but don't fall into the trap of thinking that `const char*` points to a C string. It is simply a pointer to `const char`. It is almost always **used** as a pointer to a C string, but sometimes it isn't. For example, `char ch; const char *ptr = &ch'`. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot assign a `const char*` pointer (a pointer-to-const) to a `char*` pointer (a pointer-to-non-const), they are not compatible.

If you don’t mind your class pointing to the original character data as-is, then you can make the `str` member be a pointer-to-const:

```cpp
class MyString {
    const char* str;
public:
    MyString(const char* _str) : str(_str) {}
};
```

You will just have to make sure the original character data outlives your `MyString` object.

This is likely not what you want.  The other option is to make your class *copy* the character data into itself:

```cpp
class MyString {
    char* str = nullptr;
public:
    MyString(const char* _str) {
        if (_str) {
            str = new char[strlen(_str) + 1];
            strcpy(str, _str);
        }
    }
    ...
};
```

Just be sure to follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to manage that copy correctly.  That means implementing a destructor to free the copy, and a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to make copies of the data, and a move constructor and move assignment operator to move the data around:

```cpp
class MyString {
    char* str = nullptr;
public:
    MyString() = default;

    MyString(const char* _str) {
        if (_str) {
            str = new char[strlen(_str) + 1];
            strcpy(str, _str);
        }
    }

    MyString(const MyString &src) : MyString(src.str) { }

    MyString(MyString &&src) {
        str = src.str;
        src.str = nullptr;
    }

    ~MyString() {
        delete[] str;
    }

    MyString& operator=(MyString rhs) {
        MyString tmp(std::move(rhs));
        std::swap(src, tmp.src);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

A better solution is to use `std::string` instead, which handles all of these details for you.